# Hosting java web application with tomcat and mysql database

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, tomcat, amazon-web-services, hosting

My current scenario is that I have a Java EE application built on Spring mvc and running on tomcat + mysql server.

I want to go live using a respectable Web hosting company like amazon (aws).
am expecting 2000 users per day,

please suggest me to best configuration (ram,cpu,memory,bandwidth etc) for my application.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is very hard to make a good suggestion without knowing more deeply your application. 
Anyway if the 2000 uses your system sparsely during the day it will be a very low load and can be easily handled.
I would recommend that you deploy your application on the smallest machine (t2.micro) on amazon (which is free of charge during 1 year), and do some load test... in the simple way, you may even use curl in multi-thread to simulate multi-user on your own desktop and look carefully how far your application goes until it reaches its limit, just careful that it may be disk, memory, network or cpu limited, you should observe each of this when your server starts returning errors or high latency on requests.
I guess t2.micro would be enough, if you don't fill confident, pay some cents and test with a t2.medium.
And of course after releasing your application staying observing its load, so you can decide when to increase your server.